# Is there a free PHP library that can be used for captcha

Tags: php, captcha

In the our website, we adopt reCAPTCHA to prevent spam. However, our clients complain that the validation is too complicated. I also agree that the reCAPTCHA is way too complicated for a regular person to read. It is especially hard for people who don't know English.

I found that the CAPTCHA function of mail.yahoo.com is reasonable and I don't know whether or not I can use it for free like reCAPTCHA.

Thank you

**Update**

I think my original idea is to find a free PHP library that can be used for  captcha. I just need some simple way to do the captcha rather than make my  clients feel it is so difficult even for a real human to solve the words.

Comment: Well, do they offer a library / API for their CAPTCHA? Because if they don't, the answer is probably "no".

Comment: The Most Complex CAPTCHA In the World - http://www.labnol.org/internet/favorites/the-most-complex-captcha-in-the-world/244/

Comment: My computer will be able to solve that CAPTCHA a lot quicker then I can. Hardly the most complex CAPTCHA in the world.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most hosts allow GD image manipulation for PHP. Its actually really easy to learn, and you could make your own captcha script in 10 or 20 minutes. That is, if you already know PHP.

This is a pretty simple script example: [linky](https://web.archive.org/web/20110613111513/http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk:80/articles/php-captcha.php)

Example:

[image: Example Captcha]

Code:

```
<?php
/*
Author: Simon Jarvis
Modified: Azmisov
Copyright: 2006 Simon Jarvis
License: GPL2
Link: http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/php-captcha.php
*/

//OPTIONS
$dwidth = 260;
$dheight = 90;
$dcharacters = 6;
//https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/jellee-typeface
$font = './jellee_roman.ttf';
$possible = '234679ABCDEHJLMNPTUVWXY';

//CODE
session_start();
function generateCode($characters) {
    global $possible;
    $code = '';
    $len = strlen($possible)-1;
    for($i=0; $i<$characters; $i++)
        $code .= substr($possible, mt_rand(0, $len), 1);
    return $code;
}
function createCaptcha($width,$height,$characters) {
    global $font;
    $code = generateCode($characters);
    $_SESSION['captcha'] = $code;
    //font size will be 75% of the image height
    $font_size = $height * 0.4;
    $image = imagecreate($width, $height) or die('Cannot initialize new GD image stream');
    //set the colours
    $background_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 20, 58, 78);
    $text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 74, 143, 200);
    $noise_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 100, 120, 200);
    //generate random dots in background
    for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/3; $i++)
        imagefilledellipse($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), 1, 1, $noise_color);
    //generate random lines in background
    for($i=0; $i<($width*$height)/150; $i++)
        imageline($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), $noise_color);
    //create textbox and add text
    $textbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $font, $code) or die('Error in imagettfbbox function');
    $x = ($width - $textbox[4])/2;
    $y = ($height - $textbox[5])/2;
    imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $text_color, $font , $code) or die('Error in imagettftext function');
    //generate random dots/lines in foreground
    for($i=0; $i<2; $i++)
        imageline($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), $noise_color);
    for( $i=0; $i<40; $i++)
        imagefilledellipse($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), 3, 3, $noise_color);
    //Apply filters
    imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, 1);
    imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_EMBOSS);
    imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_EDGEDETECT);
    imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_NEGATE);
    /* output captcha image to browser */
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($image);
    imagedestroy($image);
} 
createCaptcha($width,$height,$characters); 
?>
```

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: A captcha is **not** text-as-image. Specific rules must be followed to make it effective. While it is easy to draw in PHP, making an effective captcha takes more than 10-20 minutes. Also, you are forgetting accessibility.

Comment: This question was from 8 years ago when computer vision algorithms were still not that great at recognizing distorted text. I suspect it would still be good enough to deter most automated spam bots. If you have tips for making an effective captcha, I'm sure people would find it helpful if you posted an answer listing them.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend one more place: [phpclasses.org](http://www.phpclasses.org/), in this site, you can find all sort of PHP resources. I had to use a captcha and found it there. I downloaded it, but lost the link tough, sorry :(

Anyways, looking for a captcha class there won't take more than 5 minutes.

Try [this url](http://www.phpclasses.org/search.html?words=captcha&x=8&y=4&go_search=1)

Best regards,
David!

Comment: Hello dconde,

I cannot find any useful info on this website.

Comment: sorry about that, i missplaced the link, its ok now

Answer (score 1):

I built a simple captcha class based on GD. It even has a math mode if images are to hard for your users.

http://github.com/Xeoncross/micromvc/blob/v2.0.0/modules/core/classes/captcha.php

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there are any classes yet for this, but instead of a CAPTCHA, you could keep a collection of anti-bot questions like "Is fire hot or cold?" and use those instead of images. That method is becoming increasingly popular in web apps.

Edit: like this! http://textcaptcha.com/

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft's ASIRRA](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/asirra/), it's just pictures of cats and dogs and you have to select all the cats.